# Immutable Tags in private Docker registry?

Tags: docker, immutability, docker-registry

I am using a private Docker registry.

Is it possible to configure a private Docker registry so that Tags are immutable? It is possible to do something like this here:

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/datacenter/dtr/2.4/guides/user/manage-images/prevent-tags-from-being-overwritten/

But I don't know how to adapt that to a custom registry: https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/

Comment: You could use the hash instead of tags as those are immutable. That might be an interesting path for you.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, I think hashes are bad practice as they are not human-readable

Comment: I ended up going with Matt's recommendation of using the hash.